# Access dynamically created EditTexts

Tags: android, view

I am using the following to add EditTexts along with cancel buttons dynamically to my main activity.

**JAVA**

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
for(int i=0;i<numberOfEditTexts;i++)
{
    LinearLayout editText = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittexts,root,false);
    editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
    root.addView(editText);
}
```

**edittexts XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email_id" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_button"
        android:onClick="deleteRow"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am already using `generateViewId()`. Does that ensure unique ids?

More importantly, I want to get/set texts individually on all dynamically created EditTexts. How can I access them?

Comment: Use `.setId()` for set Ids for dynamically created UI elements.

Comment: I have done that, now how do I get the Ids?

Comment: One could use an array to store ids of individual `editText` LinearLayouts. But can I just have the id of the EditText contained by the LinearLayouts?

Comment: "One could use an array to store ids of individual". So this is no longer a question? You understand what you need to do? "But can I just have the id of the EditText contained by the LinearLayouts?" Yes, you have the id of the view.

Comment: sorry for my noobiness, but can you explain it to me please? I have trouble understanding how android assigns ids to its views... please help @JaredBurrows

Comment: You need to store the ids that you're assigning to the views so that you can pass them in to `findViewById` later.